# ImportError: cannot import name 'Command' from 'celery.bin.base'

Tags: python, celery, flower

When I run the command

```
flower -A main --port=5555
```

Flower doesn't work, the error is:

```
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Command' from 'celery.bin.base'
```

Any ideas? Main is a Django Project

Comment: Try installing python3-celery. `sudo apt install python3-celery` also `pip3 install celery`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work

Comment: Is a reported bug https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/1029 , the temporal solution is dowgraded celery to 4.4.7 as packetflow, thanks @Pax

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Flower is always lagging behind Celery, so if you use the latest Celery (they refactored the CLI) it will probably fail. Stick to 4.4.x until Flower catches up.

Comment: Here's the GitHub issue to track progress: https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/1029

Answer (score 17):

One workaround, if you prefer to avoid downgrading your Celery worker, is to run a previous version of Flower separate from your main Celery install. For example, in a container or separate venv. Flower just monitors your broker, and can be run completely separate from your Celery worker.

#### Flower in Docker example

For your Django/Celery install, run Celery [normally](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html#starting-the-worker-process) (no Flower):

```
celery -A main worker
```

For Flower, use docker [image](https://hub.docker.com/layers/mher/flower/0.9.5/images/sha256-ca71af763c3862a1e48f387163da12b8dca8dd86ab2b64b54844aac959fa54c5?context=explore) `mher/flower:0.9.5`, which internally uses Celery 4.4.6, and is [reported working](https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/1029#issuecomment-705696094).

Here is a sample `docker run` command:

```
docker run --name flower -p 5555:5555 mher/flower:0.9.5 flower --broker=redis://redis-address
```

*Note: You must change the broker address to be your broker's dns-resolvable name or ip.* For rabbitmq, use `--broker=amqp://guest@rabbitmq-address:5672//`. See the [url documentation](https://kombu.readthedocs.io/en/master/userguide/connections.html#connection-urls) for advanced options.

Once running, Flower should be available at the Docker host's IP:5555

You can alternatively create a docker-compose file encapsulating all of the arguments in the run command, and use `docker-compose up -d`.

#### Alternatives

If preferred, you can also do all this *without Docker*, using `pip install flower redis celery==4.4.7`, as long as it is separate from your main Celery install, and then run flower with `flower --broker=redis://redis-address`. A separate venv may work for this.

See the [github issue](https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/1029) for future updates on the original bug.

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue while working on celery 5.0.5 so switched to celery 4.4.7 version with flower 0.9.7 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may downgrade Celery as many people have already suggested, or, as in my case, upgrade flower to the last version, which is now 1.0.0 since july 2021 -> https://pypi.org/project/flower/.

I can confirm this last version is compatible with `celery[auth,redis,tblib]==5.1.2`.

Personally I'd suggest that you tried to upgrade packages instead of downgrading them, and that upgrading flower has less chances of breaking your project than downgrading celery.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `pip install https://github.com/mher/flower/zipball/master#egg=flower`